# Shopware 6 - add custom data to product entity with addExtension and make them appear in store-api responses

Tags: shopware

Within a subscriber to the `ProductListingResultEvent::class` I use the `addExtension` method to add some custom data to the product entity:

```
$product->addExtension('myExtension, new ArrayStruct(['foo' => 'bar']));
```

This works ok, the data are added to the product entity structure. But the response of a store-api/product-listing request **does not show** the data:

```json
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "extensions": {
                "search": {
                    "extensions": [],
                    "_uniqueIdentifier": null,
                    "translated": [],
                    "id": "018d4c57dad8727eace966d4efa56c3f",
                    "productNumber": "XYZ",
                    "autoIncrement": 369
                }
            },
...
```

However I want the data to show up in the response like this:

```json
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "extensions": {
                "search": {
                    "extensions": [],
                    "_uniqueIdentifier": null,
                    "translated": [],
                    "id": "018d4c57dad8727eace966d4efa56c3f",
                    "productNumber": "XYZ",
                    "autoIncrement": 369
                },
                "myExtension": {
                    "apiAlias": "array_struct",
                    "foo": "bar"
                }
            },
```

How can I achieve this? Is it somehow possible to set a flag `ApiAware` for a dynamic extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried creating an [entity extension](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities.html) for the product definition and adding your field with the the `Runtime` and `ApiAware` flag?

For example:

```php
class ProductExtension extends EntityExtension
{
    public function extendFields(FieldCollection $collection): void
    {
        $collection->add(
            (new JsonField('myExtension', 'myExtension'))->addFlags(new ApiAware(), new Runtime())
        );
    }

    public function getDefinitionClass(): string
    {
        return ProductDefinition::class;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx - this does the trick! Could there be any side effects?

Comment: Not as far as I know and this is the intended way to achieve what you wanted.